yarn installing a local npm package such that the local package uses node_modules of main project (ckeditor-duplicated-modules error)
In my MainProject I'm trying to install a local version of a ckeditor-5 plugin PeteCkPlugin created with the ckeditor5 package generator.
I tried using the yarn link in my local PeteCkPlugin root dir, then yarn link @PeteSpace/PeteCkPlugin in the MainProject root dir, but got a Usage Error: Invalid destination '@PeteSpace/PeteCkPlugin'; Can't link the project to itself error.
I've also tried using the yarn package.json resolutions field:
{
  ...,
  "resolutions": { 
    "@PeteSpace/PeteCkPlugin": "link:/path/to/project/PeteSpace/PeteCkPlugin" 
  },"
  ...
}

which successfully installs the package, but MainProject then fails due to an "Uncaught CKEditorError: ckeditor-duplicated-modules Read more: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/support/error-codes.html#error-ckeditor-duplicated-modules" error, as I think the local PeteCkPlugin package is using it's own PeteCkPackage/node_modules/ckeditor package, rather than the shared MainProject/node_modules/ckeditor package...
I've also tried the portal: in place of link: in the resolutions value above"...
I can't publish the package yet as it's private and I'm not yet in the right npm org.
Happy to hear any ideas that could help, I definitely don't yet understand symlinking and what's happening under the hood with yarn and npm.

I've had similar problems with yarn link over time and resorted to using yalc instead, which has worked flawlessly every time.
The process is quite simple:

Install Yalc globally

volta install yalc # or `npm i -g yalc` if you don't use volta


Publish your dependency

yalc publish # run from dependency root after build process


Link the dependency

yalc link # run from the root of your main project

You can also subscribe and autopublish on changes from your dependency.
For more information see the official readme.

Thanks so much Webber! Yes - yalc does just work without any issue, amazing. I'll leave this open a little while just in case someone knows a way that doesn't involve adding another tool to our project, in the meantime I'll use yalc as you suggest.
